# How to write a simple query or PL/SQL code in Oracle to check if order_id exists in one table before processing another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-design

I am looking to populate a table with some data and normally I would run some insert scripts or upload via a csv file. The requirements I have is that the data can only be populated in the 2nd table as long as the order_id is within the orders table.

From what I know I probably need to write some PL/SQL code to check if the order_id exists in the orders table before running the insert scripts but not sure how to write this. I would appreciate it if somebody could get me started.

This is the create statement for the Orders Table:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
    ORDER_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    STATUS VARCHAR2(9) NOT NULL,
    ORDER_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ORDER_ID),
CONSTRAINT CHK_STATUS CHECK (STATUS = 'OPEN' OR STATUS = 'CLOSED')
);
```

The create statement for the 2nd table is:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER2
(
    ORDER_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    ORDER_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(PRODUCT_ID)
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [exists](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions012.htm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes, you could check it *manually*. As HoneyBadger commented, `exists` is a way to do that, for example:

```
SQL> insert into orders (order_id, status, order_date)
  2    select 1, 'OPEN'  , trunc(sysdate - 2) from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'CLOSED', trunc(sysdate - 1) from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from orders;

  ORDER_ID STATUS ORDER_DATE
---------- ------ ----------
         1 OPEN   03.06.2022
         2 CLOSED 04.06.2022
```

Let's try to insert `order_id = 1` into `order2`:

```
SQL> insert into order2 (product_id, order_id, order_date)
  2    select 100, 1, trunc(sysdate - 2) from dual
  3    where exists (select null
  4                  from orders
  5                  where order_id = 1);

1 row created.
```

It succeeded as `order_id = 1` exists in `orders` table. What about `order_id = 3` which doesn't exist there?

```
SQL> insert into order2 (product_id, order_id, order_date)
  2    select 300, 3, trunc(sysdate) from dual
  3    where exists (select null
  4                  from orders
  5                  where order_id = 3);

0 rows created.

SQL>
```

Right, nothing was inserted.

---

But, why wouldn't you let the database do it for you? Create a **foreign key constraint** which won't let any rows to be inserted into the `order2` table unless that `order_id` exists in the `orders` table:

```
SQL> create table orders (
  2      order_id   number      constraint pk_ord primary key,
  3      status     varchar2(6) constraint chk_ord_stat check (status in ('OPEN', 'CLOSED'))
  4                             not null,
  5      order_date date        not null
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> create table order2 (
  2      product_id number      constraint pk_ord2 primary key,
  3      order_id   number      constraint fk_ord2_ord references orders (order_id)
  4                             not null,
  5      order_date date        not null
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into order2 (product_id, order_id, order_date)
  2    values (300, 3, trunc(sysdate));
insert into order2 (product_id, order_id, order_date)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.FK_ORD2_ORD) violated - parent key not
found


SQL>
```

See? Oracle won't let you do that, you don't have to *check* anything.

---

On the other hand, why two tables? Most columns are common (I presume they also share common data), so perhaps you could just add `product_id` into orders (I don't know whether `order_id` and `product_id` make the primary key, though):

```
SQL> create table orders (
  2      order_id   number,
  3      product_id number,
  4      status     varchar2(6) constraint chk_ord_stat check (status in ('OPEN', 'CLOSED'))
  5                             not null,
  6      order_date date        not null,
  7      --
  8                             constraint pk_ord primary key (order_id, product_id)
  9  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Littlefoot, thank you so much, that was so concise and brilliantly explained. You are right it would be easier to creat a foreign key constraint to handle this automatically.